# Why doesn't NullReferenceException give the name of the identifier?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-error

This happens to me all the time.  I have some code that breaks at run time with a `NullReferenceException`:

[image]

I am told the source file and the line number, but not the actual location of the attempted reference to whatever turned out to be null, in this case I can't tell if it's `_request` or `Banker`.

What's is the fundamental reason such valuable information has been omitted?

Comment: Local symbol names are not included in the compiled assembly meta-data.

Comment: Of course, in this particular example you know that the `Banker` is the problem just by looking at the code...

Comment: @Jon, derrr - you're right of course

Comment: What would the name of the "identifier" be for `((object) null).GetType()`?

Comment: @dcastro "Identifier at line 10 position 8".

Comment: @Discord Don't you get that if you have the PDB?

Comment: @MichaelStum I don't think I get the position in the line...